# Control Internet Explorer from VBA

Tags: vba, refresh, internet-explorer-11

I have created a macro/userform that creates an html file and want Internet Explorer 11 to show the page.
When you use the userform you create new data that should be shown on the page. How do I refresh the page on IE11?

I tried using meta refresh, but if the userform writes the page at the moment IE refreshes the page goes blank and stops from refreshing.

Another method I tried is sendkeys but it doesn't seem to work.

```
AppActivate "The page - Internet Explorer"
SendKeys "{F5}", True
```

nothing happens.

Are there any other options to make sure the page is refreshed and always visible? (meaning don't refresh when the file is in use by the userform)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If page is already opened then you need to find that specific page and then you can try to refresh it. you can try to find the page by its title.

See the example code below.

```html
Sub demo1()
flag = 0
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
IE_count = objShell.Windows.Count
For x = 0 To (IE_count - 1)
    On Error Resume Next
    my_url = objShell.Windows(x).Document.Location
    my_title = objShell.Windows(x).Document.Title

    If my_title Like "Microsoft" & "*" Then
        Set ie = objShell.Windows(x)
        ie.Refresh
        flag = 1
        Exit For
    Else
    End If
Next

If flag = 0 Then
    Debug.Print ("A matching webpage was NOT found")
Else
    Debug.Print ("A matching webpage was found")
End If
End Sub
```

Try to modify the title in code to match with your web page.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. But this code only creates a new window, It doesn't control an already open window. My code creates/changes the html in a text file and a browser needs to display it on a screen not viewable by the user. That is why I don't want new windows or a meta refresh since it can get stuck in the middle.

Comment: @ Andreas, Please check the modified answer may help you to solve your issue.

Comment: That looks interesting! I will have a look at it soon. Is `If my_title Like "Microsoft" & "*" Then` that I need to change to make it find the correct widow? `*` should be replaced with `my page` if the title of the page is `my page`?

Comment: * is for wild card characters. You can just add the title at the place of 'Microsoft'. Leave the * as it is. Note that it is case sensitive.

Comment: Got it working! I needed to change the line as I expected. But to `If my_title Like "My page" & "*" Then`